# SQL Server: issue with adapting Rank statement in Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ranking, rank

I have a dynamic stored procedure that start as follows with the declaration of a temp table and then an insert statement.

Can someone here tell me how I need to adapt the following line so that it creates a rank based on the groupCount (desc) instead of by Count?

When I just say groupCount instead of Count then it returns:

> Invalid column name 'groupCount'

The line in question:

```
RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc, <sel>) [Rank],
```

My procedure (first part):

```
   SET @sql = N' DECLARE @temp AS TABLE
    (
                ranking int,
                item nvarchar(100),
                totalCount int,
                matchCount int,
                groupCount int,
                groupName nvarchar(100)
    )

    INSERT INTO @temp
    (
                ranking,
                item,
                totalCount,
                matchCount,
                groupCount,
                groupName
    )
    SELECT      RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc, <sel>) [Rank],
                <sel>,
                COUNT(*) AS totalCount,
                SUM(CASE WHEN suggestedAction = recommendation THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS matchCount,
                ROUND(100 * AVG(CASE WHEN suggestedAction = recommendation THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END), 0) AS groupCount,
                ''currentMonth'' AS groupName
    FROM        LogEsc
    WHERE       dateEsc LIKE ''' + @date0 + '%''
    AND         EID LIKE ''PE%''
    GROUP BY    <sel>
    ORDER BY    groupCount desc, <sel>
        -- ...
```

Many thanks in advance for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the alias.

use

```
ORDER BY ROUND(100 * AVG(CASE WHEN suggestedAction = recommendation THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works ! If I want to order descending, can I just add desc at the end of the above ?

Comment: @user2571510 yes you should be able to add the desc after in order to order it descending.